# ¿Se puede crear un gestor de archivos con codeigniter-4?

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Tengo un proyecto en PHP puro y uso el código de un gestor de archivos para listar las imágenes en una carpeta:

```
function directorio_de_slider($ruta)
{
    // Se comprueba que realmente sea la ruta de un directorio
    if (is_dir($ruta)) {
        // Abre un gestor de directorios para la ruta indicada
        $gestor = opendir($ruta);
        // Recorre todos los elementos del directorio
        while (($archivo = readdir($gestor)) !== false) {

            $ruta_completa = $ruta . "/" . $archivo;

            // Se muestran todos los archivos y carpetas excepto "." y ".."
            if ($archivo != "." && $archivo != "..") {
                // Si es un directorio se recorre recursivamente

                //echo "<li><img src = '" . $ruta_completa ."'></li>";
                echo '
            <li>
            <img src="' . $ruta_completa . '" class="responsive-img">
            </li>';
            }
        }

        // Cierra el gestor de directorios
        closedir($gestor);
    } else {
        echo "Esto no es una carpeta<br/>";
    }
}
```

El problema es que ahora estoy creando un proyecto con CodeIgniter-4 y quiero hacer lo mismo pero, no me reconoce la ruta como un directorio.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <?php directorio_de_slider('base_url() . '/assets/img/Banners//' . $mes_actual . '/Desktop/'); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

La variable $mes_actual la obtengo así: `$mes_actual = date("m") . '-' . date("y");`

Y mis archivos están así:

[image: Directorio de imágenes]

No está funcionando como debería y creo que es porque estoy usando base_url(), sin embargo tampoco funciona al usar algo como: "../../".

¿Alguien tiene una función para gestor de archivos en codeigniter o una forma correcta de usar el parámetro para mi función?

Se lo agradecería mucho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución.
Para poder listar documentos de una carpeta en CodeIgniter se debe usar un helper:

```
helper('filesystem');
```

Y luego usas

```
directory_map($ruta)
```

Para crear un arreglo con los archivos de la carpeta que imprime algo como esto:

```
Array
(
    [Desktop\] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.png
            [1] => 2.png
            [2] => 3.png
            [3] => 4.png
            [4] => 5.png
        )

    [Med\] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1_MID.png
            [1] => 2_MID.png
            [2] => 3_MID.png
            [3] => 4_MID.png
            [4] => 5_MID.png
        )

    [Mobile\] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1_SQUARE.png
            [1] => 2_SQUARE.png
            [2] => 3_SQUARE.png
            [3] => 4_SQUARE.png
     

   [4] => 5_SQUARE.png
    )
```

)

Finalmente, con un foreach imprimí las imágenes.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <?php
                $ruta_completa = 'assets/img/Banners/' . $mes_actual . '/Desktop/';
                $map = directory_map($ruta_completa);
                foreach ($map as $maps) {
                    echo '<li><img src="' . $ruta_completa . $maps . '" class="responsive-img"></li>';
                }
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```